# Screen freezes upon screensaver when playing video

Tags: 11.04, installation, freeze, screensaver

Trying to install Natty on a Pent dual, core 2.50 GHz, 4gb ram, nvidia 8400 with 260.19.44. I have 10.10 installed and it works perfect. When i install 11.04 all goes well but when it goes in to screensaver it seems to freeze up and takes a few minutes to come out of it, cant use menu or any icons.
Was wondering if anyone has any idea if i am doing something wrong or should i change something??  TYAVMIA :-)

Comment: Please [file a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) on this issue.

Comment: [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/761865) and as such is now closed.

Answer (score 2):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/761865